# Choosing optional functions with parameters by user

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Using the help of a Stackoverflow' user I found out how to wrote a program with [optional functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437572/optional-function-to-choose-for-user/49437823#49437823). But the question stays in another form:

According to the following code, the user can choose each one of `a`,`b`,`c` function to use in calculation, maybe one of them or all of them. But what about their parameters?
If we would like to import values for parameters in chosen function(s)?

for example user want to use function `a` and `c` and import different `x`, `y`, `h`, `s` and `d`. These parameters are completely different and must be imported by user. `l` and `n` will be calculate in the code and not by user.

`Results=(a(x1,y1,h1,n)+c(s1,d1,l))-(a(x2,y2,h2,n)+c(s2,d2,l)))`
Our functions are:

```
def a(x,y,h,n):
    return x + y    
def b(z,l):
    return z - t    
def c(s,d):
    return s*d
```

The orginal code is:

```
def a():
       return 2 + 3

def b():
       return 3 - 2

def c():
       return 2*3

dic = {}
dic['a'] = a
dic['b'] = b
dic['c'] = c

funcs = str(input("which functions would you like to use?: "))
funcs = funcs.split(',')

result = 0

for i in funcs:
    result += dic[i]()

print (result)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "...would like to import values for parameters in chosen function(s)"? `import` means something very specific in Python (in fact it's a keyword)—do you mean it in that sense or did you really mean "input"?

Comment: @Martineau I just mean choosing arbitrary values.

Comment: Choose them how?

Answer (score 1):

If parameter to the functions are fixed and you know them in prior then following snippet can help you. Tried and tested in python 3.6

```
dic_var = {"a": ["x","y","h"],"b": ["z"], "c":["s","d"] }

funcs = ["a","c"]
for i in funcs:
    vars_here = dic_var[i]
    for item in vars_here:
        exec("{} = int(input('Input values for:{}'))".format(item, item) )
```

EDIT: 1

```
# Let us define n and l 
n = 10
l = 5

dic_var = {"a": ["x","y","h"],"b": ["z"], "c":["s","d"] }
execute_fun = {"a": "a(x,y,h,n)", "b": "b(z,l)", "c": "c(s,d)"}

def a(x,y,h,n):
    return x + y    
def b(z,l):
    return z - l    
def c(s,d):
    return s*d

dic = {}
dic['a'] = a
dic['b'] = b
dic['c'] = c

funcs = str(input("which functions would you like to use?: "))
funcs = funcs.split(',')

result = 0

for i in funcs:
    vars_here = dic_var[i]
    for item in vars_here:
        exec("{} = int(input('Input values for:{}'))".format(item, item) )
    exec("val = {}".format(execute_fun[i]))
    result += val

print (result)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the important part is stay still. Doesyour code satisfy this statement?

`Results=(a(x1,y1,h1,n)+c(s1,d1,l))-(a(x2,y2,h2,n)+c(s2,d2,l)))`
how does your code understand to do this?

Comment: `x2`,`y2` and... are in the program but how does code understand to choose function `a` and `b` in the right side of `resuts` after `-`. Example: `c(s1,d1,l)+b(z1,l)-c(s2,d2,l)+b(z2,l)`. after minus the equation will change according to user chooses.

Comment: @Bob See EDIT: 1

Comment: Applying `exec()` on arbitrary user input is a (potentially serious) security risk.

Comment: @RaoSahab Dear Rao, the equation has two parts before minus and after minus. we choose functions before minus but the functions after minus must be chosen by the program and be the same. I rated up ur answer by now. I need exactly the mentioned equation.